# SSAS - why 'process update' option not available for cube?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssas, olap-cube

Why does the **process update** option is available for dimensions but not available for cubes? Is there any other equivalent option to achieve process update for cubes?

Thanks.

Comment: I frequently have cubes that only need to get in the latest data available - yesterday's OLTP transactions, for example. I partition the Measure group by ReportingDate, and only process yesterday's partition.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is the main purpose of 'ProcessUpdate' in your ETL.

If you use it just to add new data, this option is called 'ProcessAdd'.

But for some changes in previous data - it's quite hard to predict. You can organize some manual combinations of processing like this one (with several additional conditions: you need to know relations between SQL-partitions/tables and SSAS-partitions of a cube):

1. Mark in SQL every used partition/table with new added flag 'NeedsToProcess'.
2. Take the list of this partitions by SSIS package.
3. Use for each loop to process (via XMLA) only changed partitions.

P.S. And answer to your 1st question is: because it's too complex task. Let us say we use MOLAP model and process SSAS DB only once per day. After SQL base is full of new (and updated old) data, we need to find ALL CHANGES to process again. So server may scan every row, it's the same as ProcessFull I quess. Or there may be some hidden SSAS-service on SQL, that marks changed rows with taking relations from DSV etc. It's just theory, but I think it's too hard for server. Even if we use 'ProcessUpdate' for a 1-million-members dimension and 20-30 hierarchies inside it - it costs several minutes to process, so what will be with billion-rows fact tables... Infinity...